# Datadog - how to honor 4xx as errors in trace.servlet.request.errors

Tags: datadog

I am trying to set up some Datadog graphs/metrics, and I want a dashboard for my APM service - a Java/Spring application on EKS, so that all http errors (4xx or 5xx) are displayed. The issue is that Datadog doesn't recognize 4xx as errors.

```
sum:trace.servlet.request.errors{service:my-app,env:dev}.as_count()
```

The metric I am using is `trace.servlet.request.errors`. Is there a way to customize such metric so that it picks up 4xx or is there a different metric that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dd.http.client.error.statuses` and `dd.http.server.error.statuses` system properties control which status codes count as errors for those metrics.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/library_config/java/

Comment: I do not see those metrics in my existing metrics list. Is that enabled on the application side?

Comment: Those are not metrics, they are system properties, you set them in the same place where you instrument your application with the tracing client

Comment: Right. So is the metric counting only `dd.http.server.error.statuses` as errors? or both?

Comment: I added 
    -Ddd.http.client.error.statuses=400-499 \
    -Ddd.http.server.error.statuses=500-599 \ as system properties
but `trace.servlet.request.errors` still don't show 4xx errors.